# Firebase.configure() stops AppDelegate:OpenUrl() from being called

Tags: ios, firebase

If FirebaseApp.configure() is added to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() (which is where it is supposed to go according to the documentation, then if the application is not in the background and something launches it via a url then

```
public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

will not get called.

But as soon as FirebaseApp.configure() is removed, then OpenURL() will be called. 
So adding FirebaseApp.configure() is interfering with the standard launching/opening actions for the app.

How is one supposed to use Firebase/Crashlytics if certain functionality of your app is reliant on OpenURL() getting called but Firebase.configure() prevents it from doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that Firebase uses method swizzling.

Try setting FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in your info.plist and see it if works.

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
```